# How to correctly pass form data to database function in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CI and have been reading documentation and following a [form tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html). However I'm struggling to get my form written to my database. Actually, the data is being written, but I'm getting the error...

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant firstname - assumed 'firstname'

Filename: controllers/form.php

Line Number: 25
```

I also ge the error for the second field I'm writing lastname. I think I'm close enough that MySQL is figuring out what I'm trying to do, but I'm still missing something.

My Form/View...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pledge Details</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>First Name</h5>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo set_value('firstname'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Last Name</h5>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo set_value('lastname'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" size="50" />

<h5>Kms/Miles</h5>
<select name="myselect">
<option value="Kms" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'Kms', TRUE); ?> >Kms</option>
<option value="Miles" <?php echo set_select('myselect', 'Miles'); ?> >Miles</option>
</select> 

<h5>Pledge</h5>
<input type="text" name="pledge" value="<?php echo set_value('pledge'); ?>" size="50" />


<br><br>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

<?php echo form_close() ?>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller...

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pledge', 'Pledge', 'trim|required|max_length[12]|decimal|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->database();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO donations (firstname, lastname)
                VALUES (".$this->db->escape($_POST[firstname]).", ".$this->db->escape($_POST[lastname]).")";

            $this->db->query($sql);

            echo $this->db->affected_rows(); 

            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why are you using `$_POST` when you can use `$this->input->post('firstname');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is coming from the following line

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO donations (firstname, lastname) VALUES (".$this->db->escape($_POST[firstname]).", ".$this->db->escape($_POST[lastname]).")";
```

You forgot to enclose your `$_POST` variables in quotes. Notice how `$_POST[firstname]` has become `$_POST['firstname']`.  It should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO donations (firstname, lastname) VALUES (".$this->db->escape($_POST['firstname']).", ".$this->db->escape($_POST['lastname']).")";
```

Also like others have said rather than doing `$_POST['firstname']` you can do `$this->input->post('firstname');`

Comment: Thanks:) What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');
$lastname = $this->input->post('lastname');

$this->load->database();

$this->db->insert('mytable', array('firstname'=>$firstname , 'lastname'=>$lastname));


echo $this->db->affected_rows(); 

$this->load->view('formsuccess');
```

It's better to use active record and also try putting the mysql process in your model and not in the controller because codeigniter is designed for that MVC